# Abrindo imagem ao clicar HTML + PHP + JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou buscando as imagens no banco de dados e está listando tudo correto, tamanho fixo e etc... Queria que quando eu clicasse nela abrisse ela maior, na mesma página, como uma modal e com a foto maior...

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist">';
echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'></p>';
echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
echo '</div>';
}   
?>
```

---

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist" onClick="openimg()">';
echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
echo '</div>';
}   
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openimg() {
    $('#blankImage').show();
    return false;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta tá bem ampla, já pesquisou por modais prontos (do bootstrap por exemplo)? Existem n formas de implementar isso

Comment: sim, ja pesquisei e estou tentando implementar, mas não estou conseguindo. Ja tentei por uma função onClick na div que abre o PHp que chama esta função

   function open() {
    $('#blankImage').show();
    return false;
    }

só para dar um show na imagem, mas não da certo, só quero que ela apareça maior na tela e não saia da tela principal, pois o usuario vai clicar e dps vai ter mais fotos para ver

Comment: Não é no PHP que vc implementa isso, isso é tarefa de front (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

Comment: segue em baixo o código

Answer (score 0):

Vendo seu código não me parece que você está utilizando nenhum framework frontend (Bootstrap, Materializecss). Então vou tentar explicar a seguir o que você precisa fazer para implementar isso.

1) Você deverá ter duas imgs, uma para ser clickada e outra para ser posta no modal.

```
<!--IMG -->
<img id="img" src="...">

<!-- MODAL -->
<div id="modal">
    <img id="img-modal" src="...">
</div>
```

2) Você deve configurar o seu CSS tanto da img que será clickada quanto do modal, isso requer um pouco de prática. Mas básicamente a lógica está em quando acontecer o evento de click o #modal será mostrado e o src da img clickada passa para a img do modal.

```
// Código JS

let img = document.querySelector('#img');

img.addEventListener('click', function(event){

    let modal = document.querySelector('#modal');
    let img-modal = document.querySelector('#img-modal');
    img.setAttribute('src', event.target.src);

    // No CSS o #modal deve esta com o display none.
    modal.style.display = 'block';

}, false);
```

> Se você tiver dificuldade em implementa a parte do front-end (CSS e JS) então recomendo o link abaixo.
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Por último, tenho uma dica de código. Prefira sempre adicionar o código PHP dentro do HTML e não o contrário.

Exemplo 1:

```
<div>
<!-- difícil de ler -->
<?php if ($titulo == 'alguma coisa') {
    echo "<h1>". $titulo ."</h1>";
} ?>
</div>

<!-- fácil de ler -->

<?php if ($titulo == 'alguma coisa'): ?>
    <h1><?= $titulo ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?
```

Exemplo 2:

```
<!-- difícil de ler -->
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist" onClick="openimg()">';
echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
echo '</div>';
} ?>

<!-- fácil de ler -->

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>

    <div id="imagelist" onClick="openimg()">
        <p>
            <img src="<?= $row['location'] ?>">     
        </p>
        <p id="caption"><?= $row['caption'] ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;
```

> Procure sobre sintaxe alternativas com PHP e a sintaxe curta do echo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso, recomendo a utilização do Magnific Popup.
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/
Que é um lightbox de imagens, também trabalha bem com galerias.

Sua implementação é simples:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Comment: Veja em [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42) sobre respostas baseadas somente em links externos.

Comment: u n h u n , o k